# using a creation date of files and adding it to the name of the files in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a lot of files which I want to edit all the names by including the creation date of files.

This what I have so far, but it does not work:

```
a='c:\test_for_namn_andring\*.*';

file_info=dir('c:\test_for_namn_andring\*.*');

names={file_info.name};
dates={file_info.date};

for i=3:length(names)

   oldfilename = names;
   newfilename = (strcat(names(1,3:end), dates(1,3:end)));
   newfilename = fullfile(a, newfilename);
   movefile(fullfile(a,oldfilename{i}),newfilename);

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar in the past. Here is the code, adjusted to your needs

```
% define params
folder = 'd:/test';
name_filter = '*.*';                % any filter, e.g. '*.txt'
date_format = '_yyyymmddHHMMSSFFF'; % define the desired date string format

% process
f = dir(fullfile(folder, name_filter));
f([f.isdir]) = [];
names = {f.name}';
fullnames_old = cellfun(@(x) fullfile(folder, x), names, 'UniformOutput', false);

dates = cellstr(datestr([f.datenum]', date_format));  
[pathstr, name, ext] = cellfun(@(x) fileparts(x), names, 'UniformOutput', false);
fullnames_new = cellfun(@(x, d, e) fullfile(folder, [x, d, e]), name, dates, ext, 'UniformOutput', false);
status = cellfun(@(x, y) movefile(x, y, 'f'), fullnames_old, fullnames_new);
assert(all(status), 'failed!');     % check result
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
file_info = dir(a);

for ii = 1:length( file_info )
    if ~ file_info(ii).isdir
        oldName = fullfile( a, file_info(ii).name );
        newName = fullfile( a, sprintf( '%s_%s', file_info(ii).name, file_info(ii).date ) );
        movefile( oldName, newName );
    end
end
```

You should probably also check the return from `movefile` to handle errors. See [the doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/movefile.html) for more.

Comment: I get error Error using movefile
No matching files were found.

Comment: works as intended here, please learn to debug: http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f10-60570.html and http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2012/07/03/debugging-in-matlab/